# What is the best practice to find mongo documents count?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

Wanted to know the performance difference between countDocument and find query.

I have to find the count of documents based on certain filter, which approach will be better and takes less time?

db.collection.countDocuments({ userId: 12 })

or

db.collection.find({ userId: 12 }) and then using the length of resulted array.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use `db.collection.countDocuments()` if you don't need the data. This method uses an `aggregation` pipeline with the filters you pass on and only returns the count so you don't waste processing and time waiting for an array with all results.

This:

```
db.collection.countDocuments({ userId: 12 })
```

Is equivalent to:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { userId: 12 } },
   { $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, Rafael for answering.